# Problem with routes in functional testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, nested, functional-testing, nested-resources

I'm making a simple test project to prepare myself for my test.
I'm fairly new to nested resources, in my example I have a newsitem and each newsitem has comments.

The routing looks like this:

```
resources :comments

resources :newsitems do
    resources :comments
end
```

I'm setting up the functional tests for comments at the moment and I ran into some problems.

This will get the index of the comments of a newsitem. @newsitem is declared in the setup ofc.

```
test "should get index" do
    get :index,:newsitem_id => @newsitem
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:newsitem)
end
```

But the problem lays here, in the "should get new".

```
 test "should get new" do
    get new_newsitem_comment_path(@newsitem)
    assert_response :success
 end
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"/newsitems/1/comments/new"}
```

But when I look into the routes table, I see this:

```
new_newsitem_comment GET    /newsitems/:newsitem_id/comments/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
```

Can't I use the name path or what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in the way your test specifies the URL. The error message is:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"/newsitems/1/comments/new"}
```

and of course there is no action called "/newsitems/1/comments/new". You want to pass the hash  `{ :controller => :comments, :action => :new, :news_item_id => 1 }`.

The right syntax is simply:

```
get :new, :news_item_id => 1
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue with functional testing where I had many nested routes.  This helped immensely!  Thanks @zetetic

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Rails 3)

Try this in your `routes.rb`

```
GET    'newsitems/:newsitem_id/comments/new(.:format)' => 'comments#new', :as => :new_newsitem_comment
```

Comment: Still the same problemen.
I'm using     
get :index,{:controller => "/comments",:newsitem_id => @newsitem}
now and it doesnt return any errors. But this will just get me to the host:port/comments/new right? But it shouldn't be a problem since I give the newsitem with it right?

Just find it so strange why I cant use the paths :s

Comment: Given you actually specify nested resources in `routes.rb`, I think you should remove that line completely. Rails should have set up a named path for you. Check the output of `rake routes`, but it should be something like `new_newsitem_comment`